# R: Trying to select a specific variable created in a dataset by a function in R with a sequence of inputs

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I am very new to R, and having an issue that I just can't figure out.

I have created a very basic function that calculates cluster size, but I can't extract the cluster size data when using a sequence of inputs rather than just one X value. Here is the beginning of the code which uses public data:

```
library(lme4)
library(ICC)
library(randomizr)
library(multiwayvcov)
library(lmtest)
library(knitr)
library(pwrcalc)
library(Hmisc)

data(balsakhi)
baseline_subset <- subset(balsakhi, !is.na(pre_mathnorm))  # remove the NA values 

baseline_mean <- mean(balsakhi$pre_mathnorm, na.rm = TRUE)
baseline_sd <- sd(balsakhi$pre_mathnorm, na.rm = TRUE)

baseline_mean
baseline_sd

cluster_var_subset <- as.factor(baseline_subset$schoolid)              

outcome_subset <- baseline_subset$pre_mathnorm                                    
icc <- ICCest(cluster_var_subset, outcome_subset, data = baseline_subset)
rho <- icc$ICC       

expected_effect_size <- 0.4  
treated_mean <- baseline_mean + expected_effect_size
```

And here is the cluster size function, which works totally fine:

```
# Cluster size function
clus_size_function =  function(total_clusters) {
  twomeans(m1 = baseline_mean, m2 = treated_mean, sd = baseline_sd, nratio=1, power=.8, sig.level = .05) %>% 
  clustered(numclus = total_clusters, rho = rho) 
}


total_clusters = 36

clus_size <- clus_size_function(total_clusters)
clus_size <- clus_size$`Average per cluster`
clus_size
```

But the issue is, that I want total_clusters to be several different values, such as:

```
total_clusters = seq(35, 60, by=1)
```

But if I do this, I get the following error:

```
Error in if (tot <= 0) { : the condition has length > 1
```

And I cannot figure out how to get just the $`Average per cluster` variable from the clus_size dataframe created by the function. Could anyone point me to the right solution?

Thanks so much for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `clus_size_function()` is not vectorized. It works when `total_clusters` is length 1, but when it has a length greater than 1 it will throw the error you encounter.

What you want to do is apply that function to each element of the vector directly. We can use [`lapply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html) to apply a function to each element or a list or vector.

```r
clus_size_list <- lapply(total_clusters, clus_size_function)
```

This creates a list where each element is equivalent to the output of `clus_size_function(n)`, where `n` is a scalar (or vector of length 1). If you inspect the first element you can see this:

```r
clus_size_list[[1]]
#      Two-sample t-test power calculation 

#                         m1 = -0.003339773
#                         m2 = 0.3966602
#            n1 (unadjusted) = 100
#            n2 (unadjusted) = 100
#                        rho = 0.09554588
#        Average per cluster = 12
# Minimum number of clusters = 35
#              n1 (adjusted) = 206
#              n2 (adjusted) = 206
#                  sig.level = 0.05
#                      power = 0.8
#                alternative = two.sided
```

It appears you are trying to calculate the average per cluster with different cluster sizes. To obtain this, we can iterate over `clus_size_list` and extract the `"Average per cluster"` element. In this case I will use [`vapply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html), which is like `lapply()`, except here I am asking it to return a numeric vector (which will be our data frame column) rather than a list:

```r
avg_per_cluster_df <- data.frame(
    total_clusters,
    avg_per_cluster = vapply(
        clus_size_list,
        \(x) x[["Average per cluster"]], numeric(1)
    )
)

head(avg_per_cluster_df)
#   total_clusters avg_per_cluster
# 1             35              12
# 2             36              11
# 3             37              11
# 4             38              10
# 5             39              10
# 6             40               9
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I was looking for -- super helpful!